# Get SubFolders using Sharepoint REST API and show them in HTML DIV

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, html

I want to retrieve Subfolders using SP REST API and check if there is any created folder and If it exists, display HTML content like: `<label>SubFolder Title</label>` for each SubFolder. All dynamically. Can someone help me?

Ex:

- Folder Level 1
  - Folder Level 1.1
    - Folder Level 1.1.1
- Folder Level 2
  - Folder Level 2.2
- Folder Level 3

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items?$expand=Folder&$select=Title,Folder/ServerRelativeUrl
```

It'll return a path, which than could be split and represented the way you need to.

/sites/Testing/Shared Documents/Parent Docs

/sites/Testing/Shared Documents/Parent Docs/Child Docs

/sites/Testing/Shared Documents/Parent Docs/Child Docs

/sites/Testing/Shared Documents/Parent Docs/Child Docs/Child Docs